# background of multiline cell in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, nimbus

I make a table with multiline cell, it worked fine, but I want to change the color of a single row after making specific colomns muliline cell, not the color of the whole colomn. How can i do that?

here is an image after making colomn 2 multiline cell, but the whole colomn become white
[image]

this is what i did :

```
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer( new TextAreaRenderer2()); 

String test = "sunday \n monday ";

jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(test, 0, 3);
jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(test, 0, 1);
jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(test, 0, 2);
```

and this is  TextAreaRenderer2 class :

```
public class TextAreaRenderer2 extends JTextArea
     implements TableCellRenderer {

     public TextAreaRenderer2() {

         Font font = new Font("Aparajita", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 16);

         setLineWrap(true);
         setWrapStyleWord(true);
         setBackground(Color.yellow);
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
         setFont(font);

     } 

     @Override
     public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jTable,
          Object obj, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
          int column) {

         setText((String)obj);
         setBackground(Color.WHITE);


         return this;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `TableAreaRenderer2` class, in the `getTableCellRendererComponent` method you should set the background color based on the row. Something like this:

```
if (row % 6 < 3) {
  setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
} else {
  setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}
```

The above code will make 3 rows light gray the next 3 white and repeat the same pattern.

Comment: ok i'll do that. one more thing , how can i make the alignment of the text in the center of the cell???

Comment: The returned component must be a JLabel that you need to align the text to.

Answer (score 1):

this turned out to be one of **THOSE** questions:

- thinking it's a nice question to demonstrate how-to get the correct state-dependent visual properties in a custom renderer
- implementing and testing a quick example
- which is not working as expected
- starting a debug session

... hours later .. being disgusted by some Nimbus pecularity.

Starting with the correct thingy to do: in your custom renderer (of whatever type), have a reference to a default renderer of the table and configure the custom rendering component with the properties of the default. That way, you'll the custom renderering component looks the same as the default (selected, striping, focus ...) except for the state you want to be explicitly different

```
public static class TextAreaRenderer2 extends JTextArea implements
        TableCellRenderer {

    private TableCellRenderer delegate;

    public TextAreaRenderer2(TableCellRenderer delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        // initial config
        Font font = new Font("Aparajita", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 16);
        setFont(font);
        setLineWrap(true);
        setWrapStyleWord(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
            int column) {
        // configure content
        setText((String) value);
        // get a configured component from the delegate
        Component comp = delegate.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, 
                value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        // configure myself as appropriate
        setBackground(comp.getBackground());
        setForeground(comp.getForeground());
        setBorder(((JComponent) comp).getBorder());
        return this;
    }
}
```

This looks good in each core LAF ... except Nimbus: there we get a small white border around the area in the rows with the alternate Color. At first sight looks like an opacity flaw, oh, yes - forgot to explicitly set the opacity to true

```
// initial config
...
setOpaque = true;
```

Now we get a small dark border around the area in the rows with normal color. Strangely that dark is the color of *viewport* - ?

At the end of the day (skipping the hours :-) it turns out that textArea in Nimbus has a special ui state NOTINSCROLLPANE. In that state, the TextAreaPainter fills an area reduced by about 2px insets (no idea why). When not used in rendering, setting opacity to true is good enough to make it fill the complete area. When used in rendering nothing helps but ... adding it to a JViewport (thus faking the state) and returning the viewport as rendering component (no idea why that difference).

```
public static class TextAreaRenderer2 extends JTextArea implements
        TableCellRenderer {

    private TableCellRenderer delegate;
    JComponent parent;
    public TextAreaRenderer2(TableCellRenderer delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        // initial config
        Font font = new Font("Aparajita", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 16);
        setFont(font);
        setLineWrap(true);
        setWrapStyleWord(true);
        parent = new JViewport();
        parent.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
            int column) {
        // configure content
        setText((String) value);
        // get a configured component from the delegate
        Component comp = delegate.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, 
                value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        // configure myself as appropriate
        setBackground(comp.getBackground());
        setForeground(comp.getForeground());
        setBorder(((JComponent) comp).getBorder());
        // return the viewport we are added to
        return parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Glad I didn't start on this question during my weekend ;-)